# What image resolution do I need for an imageview of 100dp x 100dp in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I have an imageView in which I want to display several different logos and its dimensions are 100dp by 100dp . Is there an optimal resolution or Android Studio is doing it automatically?

Comment: take a look at this site: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/ there you can type in the value and you will see what you need in different resolution

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which device your app is aiming for.
You can prepare various size of images and store it in each res/drawable-xxxxx folder to be applied optimal automatically.
Android Studio will try to find the right resolution of your device, and try to find the corresponding drawable folder.
If there is no such folder, or if file is not in that folder, Studio will automatically select any name-matching files from other drawable folders.

**Example**

Suppose you have "logo.png" file with 100*100 resolution in res/drawable-xhdpi folder,
and 200*200 resolution in res/drawable/xxxhdpi folder.

If you run your app with xxxhdpi device, 200*200 one will automatically be loaded.
If you run your app with xxhdpi device, one of 2 images will automatically be selected.
Note that Android will take that image with xxhdpi resolution, so the image will be displayed with different size.

You can avoid this issues with ImageView.scaleType.
If you fix ImageView's size to 100p*100dp and scaleType to FIT_XY, your image will be always displayed properly.